# Min-Width and Initial-Scale in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap for the first time. My design needs to have a minimum width of 400px. When I load the page on a device with a narrower width (my Nexus 5 has a width of 360px), it overflows the viewport, and horizontal scrolling is needed to view the content. I would like it to be automatically scaled to fit the viewport. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You want to do this, not involving the grid system?

Comment: @Mikey - I don't understand the question, and it may be because I am very new with Bootstrap.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: How does that solve my min-width problem?

Comment: I don't think it is solvable setting a min-width and expect that the scrollbar does not appear. Also, it is not very responsive setting up a min-width. Not to sound mean but why do you need a minimum width? What is so important for a responsive design to have a min-width? The grid system is very flexible and will automatically adjust see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36497epd/

Comment: Plus you can specify the layout for different screen sizes, just try to make the width of the fiddle larger and smaller and you will see what I mean.

Comment: My design has a logo that's 400px wide. I also have an image in a `.container` that is 350px wide, which, with the `.container` padding adds up to a width of 382px.

Comment: Bootstrap has also a solution for that: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive or maybe you don't want to resize images then I would go for a smaller image size and loading these images with media queries on small devices. Thus you would have high-res for desktop/laptop and low-res for tablet/phone or something like that

Comment: @Mikey - I ended up using responsive sizing for the images, which is what you suggested. If you add that as an answer, I will accept it so you get the credit.

Comment: Ok cool that it worked out for you. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment, you can use a responsive image in bootstrap.  See this link:http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Answer (score 0):

you answered you own question, you need to set your body to have a min width.

```
body{
   min-width:1000px; /* suppose you want minimun width of 1000px */
   width: auto !important;  /* Firefox will set width as auto */
   width:1000px;             /* As IE ignores !important it will set width as 1000px; */
}
```

Comment: That's what I use, in my case the value is 400px. That's not the problem. The problem is that when I load it in the browser on the phone, it overflows the viewport. I want it to scale to fit the viewport.

Comment: here's a typical viewport
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
refer to this link, it may help
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag